# GitAttributes -[attribute]=[value]: why apply "-" and assign a value?

Tags: git, gitattributes

I understand most of the `gitattributes` options, after reading up on them over the past couple days. However, there's one configuration type in the [gitattributes to solve all your problems](https://gist.github.com/paulcbetts/2802523) GitHub gist (GistHub?) that I can't quite figure out. A couple of lines in the 3rd set of attributes have something like

```
*.vb -text=auto
```

I understand most of the parts of this line by themselves, but together I'm not sure what it means. The `*.vb` is saying "use this setting for files with a `.vb` extension". Meanwhile, the `-text` means "unset the `text` attribute, or set it to false, for files with the extension `.vb`" and the `=auto` means "set the attribute `-text` to the value `auto` for files with the `.vb` extension".

This is where my confusion lies: how can you unset something at the same time that you set it? How can you set something to two values (here, `false` and `auto`) at the same time? Is this some secret ninja method to supercharge your `gitattributes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bit of git source code that actually parses attribute lines:

```
            if (*cp == '-' || *cp == '!') {
                    e->setto = (*cp == '-') ? ATTR__FALSE : ATTR__UNSET;
                    cp++;
                    len--;
            }
            else if (!equals)
                    e->setto = ATTR__TRUE;
            else {
                    e->setto = xmemdupz(equals + 1, ep - equals - 1);
            }
            e->attr = git_attr_internal(cp, len);
```

(from `attr.c` in git 2.1.0).  In this case, `*cp` is the character at the start of the attribute, e.g., the `-` in `-text` or the `t` in `text`; `equals` is the position of the `=` character, if any; and `e` is the internal data structure being set up.

What this means is that:

```
-text=anything
```

"means" the same thing as just plain `-text`, because the test on `*cp` occurs before (and then excludes entirely) the test for `=`.  Similarly, `!text=foo` just "means" `!text`: everything after the `=` winds up quietly ignored.

It seems unwise to depend on this behavior, and probably git should emit a warning.  But the answer is (apparently) that this is just really `-text`.

Comment: Huh, so the gist is wrong/misinformed and should be updated. It seemed like that part was a comment or something anyway, so I'm not too surprised. I'm just annoyed I spent all that time searching to find out what I suspected already.

Comment: `attr.c`.  Let's see if I can find a link... ah: https://code.google.com/p/git-core/source/browse/attr.c (lines 184 onward)